# destructuring error despite correct destructuring (eslint)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I have a class:

```
export default class DepartmentItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      name,
      location,
      position,
      salary,
      age,
      citizenship,
      description
    } = this.props.department;
    const { link, tag } = this.props.department.url;
    const { isToggleOn } = this.state;
  }
}
```

For brevity the constructor is not added.

Despite destructuring the props i still get the eslint error saying `Muse use destructuring props assignment`. I believe I did this correctly, and double checked against the AirBnB eslint configs, but the error remains.

How did I get rid of the error (fixing it, not making a rule to ignore it).

Comment: Try and destructure directly from `this.props.department`, add after `description` `url: { link, tag}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of picking from `this.props.department`, just nest the destructuring.

```
const {
  department: {
    name,
    location,
    position,
    salary,
    age,
    citizenship,
    description,
    url: {
      link, tag
    }
  } = this.props;
```